# What is the difference of learning Latent features using SVD and using embedding vectors in deep network

Tags: deep-learning, svd, word-embeddings

Traditionally, singular value decomposition (SVD) can be used to learn latent feature of user and items according to user-item rating matrix.

Recently, researchers use embedding layers as the input layer of a deep neural network to learn latent representation of entities, like users or items.

What is the difference between these two? What is the possible advantages of embedding method over SVD?

Comment: Well one important advantage of neural networks over SVD (and many other linear models) is, it is able to learn non-linear features.

Comment: Perhaps [this paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/Q15-1016) could help a bit.